# How can i solve this error? My localhost version is WampServer2.0f

Tags: php, mysql

Problem:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $cn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbRIMA01");
    $sql = "insert into pages(name, content) values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['content']."',)";
    if(mysqli_query($cn, $sql))
    {
        print 'Data Saved';
    }
    else{
        print mysqli_error($cn);
    }
}
?>
<br/>
<form method="post" action="">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/><br/>
    <br/>
    <label>content</label>
    <textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove the `,` before the last `)` in your query

Comment: Parameterize your query.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last `,` from your query (just before the closing brace).

```
$sql = "insert into pages(name, content) values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['content']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a tailing comma (`,`) before your `)`. Remove it and you should be OK.

Mandatory comment:
Using string replacement like this will leave your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.